# Identifying old components

Tags: components

Can anyone tell me what the compenents ringed in red are please?  I think they're resistors (The circuit is from 1978) but I can't find any reference to resistors in this form on the internet.  If they are resistors can someone tell me:

1/ How to read the rating.  i think it's top to bottom e.g. the ones on the right are 100K but a couple only seem to have two colours above the white stripe.

2/ How to identify a current equivalent.

3/ Why would the be in this form rather than the cylinder shape used on other parts of the board.

As can be seen from the bank on the right they have pretty much disintegrated; there is one at the front of that bank where the body has detached from the legs completely.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Old components]

Comment: Just out of interest: which synth is this?

Comment: 47 nF and 100 nF capacitors - looks like a jupiter synth circa 1982 (if it is a synth)?

Comment: Definitely looks like an [Oberheim OB-1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310013/advice-to-replace-a-discontinued-battery) ;-D

Comment: Thanks all.  Bonus points to @JimmyB for correctly idenfitying the Oberheim OB-1. ;-)

Comment: They are film caps, probably Philips brand, and they are broken from bad design (hole spacing too large) and sloppy assembly (the leads could have been formed). Philips spun off their passive components manufacturing long ago.

Comment: @Andyaka the dead giveaway that it's a synth was the CEM3310 IC, that's an envelope generator chip.

Comment: This synth was manufactured in 1978.  And being American I'm not sure if the components would be Philips; most of the components that I can read seem to me made by RCA.
They're probably broken from spending too long in my garage and being exposed to temeratures slightly below 0C up to probably about 30C - as well as just being nearly 40 years old.  Even tho' it has a very solid custom flight case my garage has a habit of damaging things! I just hope I can repair it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are polyester capacitors.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Electronics Sparkx](http://vraj181.blogspot.ie/2016/02/capacitor-color-codes.html).*

Answer (score 1):

These are most likely capacitors. See for example [here for colour coding description](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_5.html).

Answer (score 0):

They look like polyester capacitors, [color codes in this link](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_5.html)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are looking at capacitors. For finding the values of the part you can fall back on E6, E12 and E24 ranges. In most situations you will find the part falling in the E12 range.  So for the first 2 rings 10,12,15,18,22,27,33,39,47,56,68,82. This helps to find the first and second ring. The third ring is the multiplication factor. 
So a component with yellow - purple (4-7) and a multiplier 3(000) brings you to 47000 pF or as stated already 47 nF. Reading the rings in a different order does not bring you in the E12 range and is therefore wrong.